Understanding the Funct6 field in shift immediate instruction in RISC-V
The following figure shows the instruction format of the RISC-V architecture.

Also in the following figure, that is from Computer Organization and Design, RISC-V edition, 2nd edition, the three fields of R and I-format of some instructions of the RISC-V instruction set are specified.

My question is about shift immediate instructions (slli, srli and srai). These instructions use I-format (the second row in the first figure, above). The leftmost field of the format (imm[11:0]) is 12 bit wide. These shift immediate instructions use a 5-bit constant (known as shamt) to specify the number of bits that are shifted. These five bit specify imm[4:0]. So, there are another 7=12-5 bits (i.e. imm[11:5]) in the immediate field (corresponding to the funct7 field in R-format). But in the book (i.e. the second figure, above), for these instructions, a funct6 field is specified (in the rightmost column) instead of funct7. Please explain why.

RiscV spec v2.1 Vol 1 User Level ISA duplicate opcodes listing? - looks relevant; I'd expect the layout for RV32I has the bits in the same places as RV64I, and that means a 6-bit shamt with shamt[5] == 0.  In RV32I mode, they fault if that's not the case.  (I think this is the answer but that was just from a quick partial read of the first google hit that came up.)

This question is similar to: RiscV spec v2.1 Vol 1 User Level ISA duplicate opcodes listing?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
